# Are the integers closed under addition... really?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

Okay so I'm a 3rd year undergraduate studying Mathematics. I've proved in group theory countless times that the **integers** are closed under addition.

It's obvious to me that they are.

However this has just put a little bit of a spanner in the works and I'd like to see your thoughts on this.

Take the infinite sum: $S = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x<1$.
[The geometric series is only convergent for $|x| < 1$.  Maybe this is part of the issue. ---PLC] 
 [There are many other cases of these, take the well known one from physics that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}^\inf n  = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3+.. = \frac{-1}{12}$]
A well known result.

Now let's differentiate this, with respect to $x$.

$\frac{d S}{dx} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3+ ...= \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ 
Now treating $S$ as a function of $x$ let's substitute in $x = -1$ 
This gives $S = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ... = \frac{1}{4}$

Now I have a sum of integers added together and I get: $\frac{1}{4}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ 
 Thus the integers are not closed under addition.

Now I assume the problem here is as always: *infinity*. The gap between infinite sums and normal sums always seems to provide these little strange problems. It's commonly accepted that both $S = \frac{1}{4}$ and the integers are closed under addition.

Let's get as philosophical here as you like..

**EDITS..**

My motivation for this question came from a Numberphile video on youtube: 
http://youtu.be/PCu_BNNI5x4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww

 Who state an alternate proof as: 
Given $S_1 = 1 +1 - 1 - 1.. = \frac{1}{2}$. Proved in the first link.
Let $S_2 = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ... $
So $2S_2 = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ...$
              $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ...$
 Now by adding coloums we can easily see that:
$2S_2 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + .. = \frac{1}{2}$ by $S_1$.
$S_2 = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: This is a limit and limits need not be in the set you are working with, they'll probably be in the derived set(set of accumulation points)

Comment: What you call "addition" is actually divergent series regularization via analytic continuation (and as you observe, $\Bbb Z$ isn't closed under this process). Whether you call this process "addition" or not depends on how literary and poetic you want to wax. What is your actual question?

Comment: Would you consider the sum $1+1+1+\cdots$ to be confusing also, for the same reason?

Comment: The geometric sum formula you mention works only for $|x|<1$, not $x<1$.

Comment: Yeah If you want to take it true for only mod (x) < 1 then take the example Trevor wilson stated, which = 1/2

Comment: Actually I just meant to allude to the fact that the series $1+1+1+\cdots$ _diverges_.

Comment: oh sorry, I read it as $S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +... = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: «Now I assume the problem here is as always: infinity.» Hm, not really: The problem here is that **you** are using concepts outside of their field of validity. In an abelian group there is no notion of «infinite sum» so anything you find using it is going to be absurd.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you are equivocating: using "closed under addition" to mean two different things.  If you fix this problem, does a substantial question remain?

Comment: You have a typo in the line after `Now let's differentiate this, with respect to x.` you need a minus sign on the RHS

Comment: @Nasser The typo is in the equation before that.

Comment: @jakey: You say you aren't sure for which values of $z$ the geometric series converges.  Are you aware of the difference between convergence of an infinite series and various summability methods which can (sometimes, and in various ways) attach a number to a divergent series?

Comment: If you want to claim that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for all $x< 1$: this may be true according to certain summability methods.  Which one do you have in mind?  (Saying "well known from physics" is not enough: there are things that are done differently in physics and mathematics.)  For instance, the series is **Abel summable** when $x= -1$, but not for $x< -1$.

Comment: "Closed under addition" is very different from "closed under addition and an infinite summation method".

Comment: Perhaps you should also rumiate on the (in some sense simpler) case of the "rationals closed under addition" property. Compare with $\pi = 4/3 - 4/5 + 4/7 - 4/9 +\cdots$

Comment: If we allow divergent sums, we not only get rid of closure, but also must throw away any notions of commutivity and associativity. For instance, take the well known $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$. Just by grouping terms differently (using associativity), it can be either 0 or 1, and if we allow rearranging them (using commutivity), then we can get any number we please.

Comment: there is another typo in $dS/dx$, the 1 on the RHS must disappear, i.e. $dS/dx=2x+3x^2+...$

Comment: @flonk no there isn't. The 1 comes from differentiating the $x$ term. Write it out on pen and paper and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @jakey: uh of course, sorry!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When it is said that "$X$ is closed under binary operation $\circ$", it means that for any $a$ and $b$ in $X$, $a \circ b$ is in $X$. It is easy to prove (by a simple induction) that any finite sum is therefore closed in $X$.

However, *infinite* sums are defined with a *limit* (of the partial sums), which means they don't just depend on the operation $\circ$, but also require a *topological* structure defined on $X$. Now the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ do have a standard topological structure in addition to their algebraic structure, it's the discrete topology, and it comes from the order on $\mathbb{Z}$. However, in this system, there is actually *no limit* of the sequence of partial sums $1$, $1 - 2$, $1 - 2 + 3$, ... (*) and so no infinite sum. In fact, an infinite sum of integers can only have a limit if all but finitely many of its terms are $0$. Another subtle flaw is that when you took a "derivative", that means you passed from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and evaluated a function on $\mathbb{R}$ on the right side, to obtain a "sum" for the left (which may be a valid technique, giving a form of "divergent summation", but it's important to remember this is actually a *generalization* beyond the usual and strict "limit" definition of infinite summation). So you left the integers, and thus it is no surprise you'd get a non-integer result. The important point to remember though is that infinite sums and finite sums are not the same thing -- one is purely algebraic, the other leverages additional (topological) structure on the set in question, and closure is strictly algebraic.

Finally, it's important to note that this series doesn't have a sum in $\mathbb{R}$ either in the strict, limit sense.

Answer (score 28):

Summation is defined to be finite. Infinite series are just limit of a sequence which is defined as partial sums.

The integers, if so, are closed under finite sums. And therefore by definition, closed under summation.

Comment: Interesting, but who defined summation to be finite? I can't imagine there is a reference for this? And wouldn't this contradict well known infinite sums?

Comment: @jakey You're mistaking natural language meaning with mathematics.

Comment: @jakey It's true that sometimes people talk about "infinite sums" or the "sum of an infinite series" but in any case the point is that infinite sums and finite sums are different things, so $\mathbb{Z}$ can be closed under one but not under the other.

Comment: @jakey: In addition to the comments by Git Gud and Trevor Wilson, let me ask you, are the rational numbers closed under summation? In fact, are the real numbers closed under summation? It's easy, in almost every structure, to find a series which is divergent to infinity. Closure under summation means that finite summations are still within the structure. Infinities are generally handled by limits and topological structures, which are additional to the basic group structure (needed for defining the summation in the first place).

Comment: Asaf I agree, I like that answer! You are very correct and I'm glad you aren't taking as negative route as others against me! I shouldn't be punished for merely asking!

Comment: This answer is true as far as it goes, but it seems to suggest that it ought to be possible for an *infinite* series of integers to converge to a real (or complex) number which is not an integer.  But in fact this is not possible, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$).  So there must be something else amiss...and there is: mjqxxxx's answer explains what it is.

Comment: @Pete: It suggests that? Where?

Comment: Well, what I got from your answer was a sort of denial that it is meaningful to talk about infinite sums of integers.  But if we view $\mathbb{Z}$ as sitting inside $\mathbb{R}$, it is meaningful.  Moreover the fact that an infinite sum of integers must be an integer does not follow from the closure under finite sums, because the same does not hold for e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$.  It follows from the *closure* of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  Or am I just reading things into your answer that you did not intend?

Comment: I guess I also find it weird that you and Git Gud each deny that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a "sum".  Yes, it is the limit of a sequence of partial sums.  We call that type of limit the **sum** of the series, right?  It's not the same thing as a finite sum and is not defined in exactly the same contexts, but it's certainly defined in *this* context, right?  (The concept is defined, I mean.)  (Git Gud's answer confuses me more; it seems to express doubt on whether the series converges; but surely he knows it diverges.  I felt like I was missing something on reading these answers...)

Comment: @Pete: Clearly the OP was confused about that. It's important, I think, to first clarify the basic definitions (in this case, that when we say closed under summation we only mean finite sums), and then expand our use of language.

Comment: @Asaf: I am rather confused about what the OP knows and does not know.  I guess I don't feel that "Summation is defined to be finite" is the best answer for a question about infinite sums....but I don't know what kind of answer the OP is looking for.  At this point I am starting to wish that someone had *not* posted a youtube video about summability methods: it's the sort of thing that has the danger of dislodging some of the more basic material we work hard to teach students.

Comment: @Pete: I thoroughly agree with your last sentence. It is my opinion that not everything can be, and certainly it often shouldn't be, dumbed down into a short video, or blog post, or whatever. Some things have to be earned by hard work, because that's the only one the student develops a correct intuition.

Answer (score 17):

The series representation
$$
1+z+z^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
is only valid for $|z|<1$ (in the sense that the left-hand side converges only in that region of the complex plane).  So you can't assert this equality (or any of its derivatives) at $z=-1$: the sum $1-1+1-1+\ldots \neq 1/2$, at least not without an agreed-upon convention for the meaning or value of a non-convergent series.  The problem doesn't have to do with infinity in this case, and the closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ is safe: the sum of an infinite series of integers will be an integer if the sum converges at all.  (Of course, it can only converge if there are only finitely many nonzero terms.)  In other cases, though, a group that is closed under finite summation may well *not* be closed under "infinite summation" (e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't contain all of its limit points); you could reasonably say that "infinity is the problem" there.

Comment: The series $$
1+z+z^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$ is valid for all $z\in\Bbb{C}\backslash\{1\}$ by the principle of analytical continuation.

Comment: I'm sorry I downvoted originally. I should have paid more attention to the convergence part of the validity statement :/

Comment: Actually, I find somewhat elegant the fact that applying the formula to 1+2+4+8+etc. yields -1.  That value would be the length of an infinitely long binary number that was all "1"'s, which is what one would receive if one subtracted 1 from 0.

Comment: @Shaun: your first comment is incorrect: the series converges exactly where mhqxxx says it does.  The series is the Taylor series of a function which is holomorphic on a larger domain, but that's not the same statement at all.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: Then my Special Functions lecturer has done me a great disservice. However, I didn't say that it converges; I said that it's valid. The LHS equals the RHS everywhere on the set $I=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\mid \lvert z\rvert<1\}$, so we can define LHS=RHS on $\Bbb{C}\backslash\{1\}$ by the principle of analytical continuation, *despite the fact that the LHS does not converge outside $I$.*

Comment: @Shaun: The principle of analytic continuation applies to holomorphic functions.  What you've written on the left hand side is not a function at all for $|z| \geq 1$ since it's given by a divergent series.  So the identity is not "valid" for exactly this reason: to be a valid identity each side has to mean something!

Comment: As for the principle of analytic continuation: it says that two holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ each defined on a domain $\Omega$ and equal on a nondiscrete subset of $\Omega$ must be equal on $\Omega$, right?  What two functions are you applying this principle to, and on what domain?

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: I did apologise in my second comment here about mjqxxxx's convergence-based validity. My first comment is correct (if my lecturer is to be believed); it's just not "valid" in mjqxxxx's sense of the word here.

Comment: (Here is what I think you meant to say: your identity holds for all $|z| < 1$, and the right hand side is defined and holomorphic for all $z \neq 1$.  Therefore the right hand side is the -- unique, by the principle of analytic continuation -- extension of the left hand side to the larger domain.  So if you want to give a meaning to the left hand side for $|z| \geq 1$ but unequal to $1$, it is reasonable from the perspective of complex function theory to have it mean $\frac{1}{1-z}$.)

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: Precisely (if my lecturer is to be believed).

Comment: @Shaun: I am not qualified to speak to whether something is mathematically correct *conditionally on the reliability of what someone else told you*.  All I know is what's mathematically correct (in this case, at least; not magically for all possible topics!).  If you are concerned that you may have learned something incorrectly, please feel free to ask about it, but let's not discuss the two things at once: that seems very confusing.  (Also in my previous comment, I should have written "holomorphic extension" instead of "extension".)

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: That's pretty funny but there's no need to be sardonic. You're right: I should be asking a question about it because it appear that my lecturer skipped a few subtle points. Thank you :)

Comment: @Shaun: Your indulgence of my being sardonic from time to time is certainly appreciated.

Comment: @supercat: You're on to something!  In fact the series literally does converge to $-1$ with respect to the $2$-adic norm.  This a is a norm in which large powers of $2$ are close to $0$.

Comment: I don't want to get to caught up in the fact that x can't be -1 in the example I used, when there appears to be many other examples available upon using the fact that $S= 1 -1 + 1-.. = \frac{1}{2}$ and I think that to deny that "without an agreed-upon convention" only emphasises to me that we need an agreed-upon convention.

Comment: @jakey: One problem with taking analytic continuation as a convention for summing divergent series is that analytic functions can be multi-valued.  That is, the value of the analytic continuation at a point can depend on the path taken in the complex plane to reach that point.  Which branch of the logarithm should you use to find "the value" of $1+1+4/3+2+16/5+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n/(n+1)=\log(-1)$?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I'm not familiar with that term.  I'm also not quite sure what to make of the behavior of repeating digits other than (base-1) in other bases.  For example, 9+90+900+... yielding -1 makes sense, but 5+50+500+... yields -5/9.  Those seem less "sensible", probably because unlike the 9+90+900+... case there's no finite integer that can be added to yield "zero".

Answer (score 16):

To clarify the situation:

- The integers are closed under addition. Any finite sum of integers is an integer.
- The integers are also complete under the usual metric. If an infinite series of integers converges in this metric, it must converge to an integer.
- The series $1-2+3-4+\cdots$ does not converge; its "sum" does not exist.
- The *Abel sum* of the series $1-2+3-4+\cdots$ is $\frac14$. This example proves that the Abel sum of a series of integers is not necessarily an integer.

There are no contradictions here!

Comment: thank you! I'm impressed with how quickly this so so many views and answers. It is all so clear now!

Comment: well I'm glad I've made you think about it! I consider that a result!

Answer (score 14):

There's no need for philosophy here.

What you call $S$ isn't a sum at all, it is the limit of a sequence, (if it happens to even converge).

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit circular. You took a derivative of a power series and then tried to argue that the sum of a set of integers is not an integer. Why should it be here? You're calculating
$S^\prime(-1)$, not $S(-1)$.

Comment: The sum of a set of integers should be an integer because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  The fact that the suggested answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ indicates that this is a divergent series for which a sum is being attached via some other **summability method** (e.g. Abel summation).

Comment: You might have a point. However, in the concrete example it is obvious that after differentiation and setting $x=-1$ all terms of the power series are still integers, so the real difficulty is elsewhere. (It is an interesting question whether one can come up with a integer-term convergent power series at $x_0\in\Bbb C$, which if instead taken at a variable $x$, differentiation with respect to $x$, and again setting $x=x_0$ in the derivative gives a series converging to a non-integer value. I guess not, because integer-term series _only_ converge if the terms ultimately become $0$ forever.)

Answer (score 1):

$$1-1+1-1+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}$$ is called Cesaro summabilty. It is an averaging used in Fourier series like the Heaviside step function, but it is **not** a sum in any usual or convergent sense. Also, when we use series, make sure that they are used within the radius of convergence, otherwise strange and unexpected results will occur.

The Platonic idea of math as an eternal verity of the Form World is being challenged by people who want to "use" math, bending it to their purposes. This isn't always bad, I guess, since we do have non-Euclidean geometries, calculus, etc. I think we have to be careful that this bending of math doesn't lead us into temptation. Exercise caution...