# What is the correct usage of the terms ‘under’ and ‘over’ in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

For example, the [Wikipedia article on rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) states that a ring is:

- an abelian group *under* addition
- a monoid *under* multiplication
- multiplication distributes *over* addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also a question about language. In mathematics we also say "under the assumption" etc. For objects like groups, rings, modules we say subgroup, subring, submodule (and not undergroup, underrring and undermodule, except in german, where we have Untergruppe, Unterrring, and Untermodul), and sometimes overring. 
Looking for "over addition" I only find "distributes over addition".
Everthing else is "under", i.e., "The unit circle in the complex plane under complex multiplication", "Help me Understand "Closed Under Addition"" , [Are the integers closed under addition... really?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634191/are-the-integers-closed-under-addition-really)